# Trying to configure iptables on Slackware 10

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, slackware

I am trying to configure `iptables` on a Slackware 10 machine. This Slackware version
is required in my class - so I cannot upgrade it. After compiling it, I want to configure 
`iptables` - however, it does not accept any commands:

```
> iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT

iptables v1.3.5: can't initialize iptables table `filter': iptables 
who? (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

- **Why iptables does not accept any configurations?**

More about my system:

- `uname -r`: 2.6.15.4
- `iptables --version`: iptables v1.3.5
- `cat /etc/slackware-version`: Slackware 10.2.0

Comment: You seriously need to upgrade.  Iptables current version is 1.4.21.  If you want to be scared at how old this is visit netfilter.org.  Your kernel is also very old and needs upgrading.

Comment: I would love to upgrade the system - unfortunately I have to use this system as it contains some vulnerabilities which we use for later security exercises.

Comment: I installed that `iptables` version as it was the *newest* I found for my kernel.

Comment: Try **modprobe ip_tables** or possibly iptables or **insmod ip_tables** or iptables.

Comment: Depending what your doing you may need to load some or all of these modules.

ipt_MASQUERADE
xt_multiport
iptable_raw
ip_set_bitmap_ipmac
ip_set_hash_net
ip_set
nfnetlink
iptable_mangle
iptable_nat
nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4
nf_nat
nf_conntrack
iptable_filter
ip_tables
x_tables

Comment: I tried `modprobe iptables`, `modprobe ip_tables`, `insmod iptables` and `insmod ip_tables` - all resulting in *FATAL: Module iptables not found.* and *insmod: can't read 'iptables': Is a directory*.
However, I can find it with `which iptables`:
*/usr/local/sbin/iptables*

Comment: /lib/modules/<kernelversion>/kernel/net/netfilter    Then modprobe or insmod the ones closest to iptables or all of them if you can't figure out which one it is.

Comment: In */lib/modules/2.6.15.4/kernel/* are only a *drivers* and *lib* folder. In the *drivers* subfolder I found a *net* containing only a file called *s2io.ko*.

Comment: find /lib/modules -iname "netfilter"

Comment: I could not find something under */lib/modules* - but when searching from / I found this list:

`pwd` => /

`find -iname "netfilter"`
./usr/src/linux-2.6.15.4/net/ipv4/netfilter
./usr/src/linux-2.6.15.4/net/ipv6/netfilter
./usr/src/linux-2.6.15.4/net/netfilter
./usr/src/linux-2.6.15.4/net/bridge/netfilter
./usr/src/linux-2.6.15.4/net/decnet/netfilter
./usr/src/linux-2.6.15.4/include/net/netfilter
./usr/src/linux-2.6.15.4/include/linux/netfilter
./root/ftp/iptables/iptables-1.4.1-rc2/include/linux/netfilter
./root/ftp/iptables/iptables-1.4.1-rc3/include/linux/netfilter

Comment: Then you will have to re-compile the kernel to add netfilter support. cd /usr/src/linux-2.6.15.4/   make menuconfig   **Networking options** then **Network packet filtering framework (netfilter)** and **IP: Netfilter configuration**.  Hit M to load as a modules or * to build it into the kernel.  Do all sub-entries. Exit saving changes.  make -j 3 && make -j 3 modules && make -j 3 modules_install && make -j 3 install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iptables/netfilter support is not built into your kernel so you need to recompile the kernel.
You will need to have **gcc** and several other things installed in order to build the kernel.

cd /usr/src/linux-2.6.15.4/

```
make menuconfig
 Networking options
       Network packet filtering framework (netfilter)
           IP: Netfilter configuration.
```

Hit M to load as a modules or * to build it into the kernel.  M means you will have to modprobe everything and * builds it in so you don't have to.

Do all sub-entries. Exit saving changes.

make -j 3 && make -j 3 modules && make -j 3 modules_install && make -j 3 install
(This could take hours)

reboot.

If you used M then modprobe the modules, else if you use * then just execute your original command.